# how to display span on top of a particular word by calculating its width and margin

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a paragraph and sub texts based on the sub text value I need to display the type on top of the word.

[image]

as in above image I have 3 sub texts `t1,t2,t3` accordingly I need to mark those range of words by keys `sentance, noun, adjective`.

```
let t1 = "some human languages in world is very unique";
let t2 = "human";
let t3 = "languages";
```

Unfortunately, the calculation of `width` and `margin Left` is proper but not working. As, one can see, `Noun is not exactly above Human` and same for `languages` it is slightly before the words.

**How to show the span exactly above the range of word by calculating width and margin?**

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-monad-xvqs35

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let w1,
    ml1,
    w2,
    ml2,
    w3,
    ml3 = 0;

  let str = "some human languages in world is very unique";
  let t1 = "some human languages in world is very unique";
  let t2 = "human";
  let t3 = "languages";

  w1 = (t1.length * 100) / str.length;
  ml1 = (str.indexOf(t1) * 100) / str.length;
  console.log(w1, ml1);

  w2 = (t2.length * 100) / str.length;
  ml2 = (str.indexOf(t2) * 100) / str.length;
  console.log(w2, ml2);

  w3 = (t3.length * 100) / str.length;
  ml3 = (str.indexOf(t3) * 100) / str.length;
  console.log(w3, ml3);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span
        style={{
          display: "inline-flex",
          alignItems: "flex-end",
          position: "relative"
        }}
      >
        <mark
          id="914_964_2511a4cf-a847-4ae2-ae22-ab253f030b77"
          data-start_offset="914"
          data-end="964"
          style={{
            color: "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
            background: "rgb(245, 245, 245)",
            position: "relative",
            padding: "0px",
            cursor: "default",
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column-reverse",
            opacity: 1,
            lineHeight: "1.5em"
          }}
        >
          some human languages in world is very unique
          <span
            class="renderLabel"
            style={{
              color: "green",
              width: `${w1}%`,
              marginLeft: `${ml1}%`
            }}
          >
            Sentence
          </span>
          <span
            class="renderLabel"
            style={{
              color: "red",
              width: `${w2}%`,
              marginLeft: `${ml2}%`
            }}
          >
            Noun
          </span>
          <span
            class="renderLabel"
            style={{
              color: "blue",
              width: `${w3}%`,
              marginLeft: `${ml3}%`
            }}
          >
            adjective
          </span>
        </mark>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
.renderLabel {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px -4px 0px -4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: initial;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.renderLabel:hover {
  background: #efefef;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.72em;
}
```

Comment: Assuming all of your sentences fit nicely on one line, and you know the sentence breakdown ahead of time, I think you could accomplish this with a 2 by X (number of words) table. Row two has all of the words separated by column, then place your identifiers in whatever column on row 1. Color the cell borders appropriately.

Comment: @alechristopher did u mean each letter should be on separate cell on a table? and then on top of that cell I need to place the key inside top cell.

Comment: A cell for each word should suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const getTextWidth = (txt) => {
        var word = document.getElementById(`id of the element to get fontFamily and fontSize`)
        if (word === null) return
        let text = document.createElement("span")
        document.body.appendChild(text)    
        text.style.font = `${window.getComputedStyle(word).fontFamily}`
        text.style.fontSize = `${window.getComputedStyle(word).fontSize}`
        text.style.height = "auto"
        text.style.width = "auto"
        text.style.position = "absolute"
        text.style.whiteSpace = "no-wrap"
        text.innerHTML = txt 
        let width = text.clientWidth
        let formattedWidth = width + "px"
        document.body.removeChild(text)
        return formattedWidth
    }
```

for `t1 = "some human languages in world is very unique"` `marginLeft:0` coz it was starting from `0th index`

for `t2, t3` margin needs to be calculated as it start from `non 0th index`

**Logic:**

- if word start from `0th index` Margin Left is zero else calculate margin. Margin left is nothing but width of the word before the sub texts
- for width pass the text along with `font-size and font-family`

```
let width = 0, marginLeft = 0
let _diff = start_offset - props.start_offset
   if(_diff > 0){
       marginLeft = getTextWidth(props.text.slice(0,_diff))
   }
   width = getTextWidth(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question.

I make a less example on [Replit](https://replit.com/@x-ray-s/word-width?v=1). You can find solutions in it.

The points are:

1. use the same element and the same content, and then get this size by `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` API, because using charset length to calculate that is not the best way, the font maybe not be a monospaced font.
2. remember to control the white space.
3. I think `transform` is better than `margin` in this scene.

sry, I visit Codepen slow, so I instead of Replit.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sentence{
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  color: green;
}

.noun{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
}

.adjective{
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="sentence">Sentence</td>
    <td class="noun">Noun</td>
    <td class="adjective">Adjective</td>
    <td class="sentence"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some</td>
    <td>human</td>
    <td>languages</td>
    <td>in world is very unique</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This will add extra spacing to text also this approach breaks the clipboard selection offset values. Anyhow I have solved the issue.